# Firebase uid returning email instead of uid

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Whenever I try and pull the uid of a user, it gives me the email instead. Does anyone have any idea why?

```
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (user != null) {
        user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
        uid = profile.uid;
        email = profile.email;
        console.log(uid);
        console.log(email);
    });
    }
```

the uid in console: blah@test.com

the email in console: blah@test.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are looking into the `providerData` it will give the uid for the provider. So, if authenticated with email it will be the email, if facebook it will be the facebook ID, twitter ID...

If you want the firebase uid you can simply go with `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid`.

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
if (user) {
    uid = user.uid;
    console.log(uid);
    user.providerData.forEach(function (provider) {
        providerUid = provider.uid;
        email = provider.email;
        console.log(providerUid);
        console.log(email);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was a huge help!